# Multiple API Keys

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, api-key

My company helps develop google map web apps for multiple clients. I am personally not a developer so please excuse me for asking a question that is likely obvious to everyone else.

I need to sign up for more than one API key because I do not want to exceed 25K on my one API Key. So is it possible to sign up for more than one API key - one for each one of my clients? This would ensure one client does not impact the rest and personally I do not exceed the api limit.

Answer (score 8):

I've created multiple keys for this purpose.

Each of your clients needs to be a separate *Project* in the Console. You then keep all of the quotas separate.

However: note that all of the keys are tied to **your** Google account. If one of your clients does something heinous it could reflect on your account and all the projects. On the other hand, because it's your account, Google will contact you about the usage and you could disable that particular key (thus stopping your client doing whatever it is).

Comment: Thanks you Andrew that is a big help! Jeff

Comment: Well if it's a big help, don't be afraid to upvote or accept the answer. Doing that helps both of us.

Comment: Having a key connected to YOUR account on a client's website won't give anyone a chance to do any harm. In the end, keys are public and anybody can read / make requests with / put them into their own website. So it doesn't matter if it's your website or a client's.

Comment: @SuperDuck At the time I wrote this answer, each key on an account was tied to a particular website and couldn't be made to work properly anywhere else. I'm not aware that's changed (but I suppose it might have).

Comment: @AndrewLeach the filtering is now optional, and recommended. But what I mean is everyone already has the key. So a key from your account doesn't need to be on a specific (ie their) website if they want to try some bad, making requests with the key. Anyone from the public is allowed what the website owner customer is allowed, as it's client-side code.

Comment: Has this statement changed? According to Fabio's answer below multiple projects won't increase your usage limit. In addition, todays [announcement](https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html) removes free quotas and you get 200 $ for your account each month for free. Thus all your different projects need to share these 200$, right?

Comment: @Adam Bear in mind that this answer is very nearly six years old, and Fabio's nearly three. Things mature and change. If you have more recent data, post an answer which reflects that. If this answer is rendered obsolete then it can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

As of the time I'm writing this, the [Developers console help](https://web.archive.org/web/20150326133300/https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/) states that

> you cannot use multiple projects to try to exceed API usage limits

So I guess the answer is no, you cannot do that.

[image: Google Projects terms of condition]