# Google maps API v3 quota limits per domain?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We maintain and host multiple client websites, but all  are on the same domain

```
http://example.com/website1
http://example.com/website2
```

If we want to use the free version of google Maps Javascript API, can we register multiple API keys? I saw on the dev console that you can add several projects to your account.

Or can we get our client to register each a key and provide it to us?

I cannot find anything like that in their terms of services

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple projects and use API keys from different project on each website, however the number of projects that you can create within one Google account is limited (approximately 16 projects IIUC).

Have a look at this question as well:

[Google Cloud Platform Project Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925949/google-cloud-platform-project-limit)

You can delegate API key creation to your customers as well and ask them to apply corresponding HTTP referrer restrictions.

Comment: Thank you. However, I saw some old post which indicated that Google did not support multiple projects as a way to bypass the quota limit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533850/multiple-api-keys (but i cannot find confirlation of that in the new T&C).  Besides, we  phoned a Google  sales rep yesterday and he seemed to believe that we could not create multiple projects or not even use out clients's keys....

Comment: My understanding it will be a ToS violation if you use multiple projects for the same app to bypass limits. However, as I understood from your description each subpath is a different app controlled by different customers, so it shouldn't be a ToS violation in this scenario. Although, I'm not a lawyer to interpret Google's ToS.